# i used flexbox css but it makes horizontal scrolling

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Before read my question, it will be better that you watch my site [enter link description here http://www.google.com](http://www.google.com)

I want to make Responsive website 
So i used **flexbox**
But some markup lines create a horizontal line for scrolling.
[image] (plz watch **red line**)

I don't know why it make horizontal scrolling

Comment: It's the images in `.dittomall-banner` causing a horizontal overflow. Try adding this to your CSS: `.dittomall-banner > img { width: 33.33% }`.

Comment: Or cut off the right side of banner3.png. There's a lot of empty space at the end

Comment: Don't post the same question twice, update the previous one instead

Comment: Could can just add `overflow:hidden` to the banner `.dittomall-banner`. The right image in the banner is extending beyond the bounds of the website.

Answer (score 1):

you can reduce image width or using code:

```
.dittomall-banner > img { width: 33.33%;float:right }
```